# Не устанавливаются пакеты на Debian

Tags: linux, debian, unix

Попытался установить по шагам PHP, начав с команды `sudo apt-get install apache2` и вот что вышло:

> dpkg: error processing package php5 (--configure):
>
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
>
> Errors were encountered while processing:
>    php5-common
>    php5-json
>    php5-cli
>    libapache2-mod-php5
>    php-pear
>    php5
>
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

В системе 174 необновленных пакета, при попытке обновить напротив многих строк написано:

> 100% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers]Permission denied (publickey).

И в итоге:

> debian Failed to fetch Read error - read

Также, в конце установки пакетов командой `sudo aptitude install libapache2-mod-php5 libapache2-mod-php5filter php5-cgi php5-fpm php5` пишет:

> Creating config file /etc/php5/apache2filter/php.ini with new version
>
> cp: ‘/var/lib/ucf/hashfile.1’ and ‘/var/lib/ucf/hashfile.2’ are the same file
>
> dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php5filter (--configure):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>
> Errors were encountered while processing:
>    libapache2-mod-php5filter
>
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
>
> Failed to perform requested operation on package.  Trying to recover:
>
> Setting up libapache2-mod-php5filter (5.6.29+dfsg-0+deb8u1) ...
>
> cp: ‘/var/lib/ucf/hashfile.1’ and ‘/var/lib/ucf/hashfile.2’ are the same file
>
> dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php5filter (--configure):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>
> Errors were encountered while processing:
>    libapache2-mod-php5filter

UPD.: В итоге применил команду `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, затем `sudo aptitude install libapache2-mod-php5 libapache2-mod-php5filter php5-cgi php5-fpm php5` (команда таки сменила свой вывод) и высветилось следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вам нужно запустить скрипт один раз? нужен ли вам веб-сервер в системе?

Comment: Возможно, нет, но команда вроде `sudo apt-get install php5` в итоге выдала такую же ошибку.

Comment: попробуйте вначале `sudo apt-get update` и посмотрите в лог `/var/log/dpkg.log` на предмет ошибок

Comment: у меня после `sudo apt-get update`: W: Failed to fetch ssh://...@.../debian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Read error - read (0: Success) и E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead. (edi

Comment: А лог `/var/log/dpkg.log` пустой.

Comment: проверьте сетевое соединение. это виртуальная машина?

Comment: да, виртуальная.

Comment: и сетевое соединение, вроде как, в порядке...

Comment: вы можете установить любой другой пакет?

Comment: нет, та же ошибка в итоге.

Comment: у меня 174 необновленных пакета, а когда пытаюсь обновить, пишет около некоторых: `100% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [Connecting to aptlyrepo@deb.it` `Permission denied (publickey)`.

Comment: исправьте ваш вопрос. проблема не в php.

Comment: попробуйте создать новую виртуальную машину и/или воспользуйтесь vagrant/docker.

Comment: обновил вопрос, добавив новую информацию.

Comment: Кто такой `aptlyrepo@deb.it`? Как ставил виртуалку? Сам и руками или качнул готовое?